# apply nbextensions with nbconvert

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I use [collapsible headings nbextension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/collapsible_headings) in jupyter notebook. When the notebook is converted to an html using `jupyter nbconvert --html mynotebook.ipynb`, the headings are no longer collapsible in the resulting html. Is it possible to apply this nbextension with nbconvert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote [this jquery script](https://gist.github.com/tarokiritani/b1b5fefa5f19e57f107bd1c3b16c742a) by myself. Just add this as a raw nbconvert script in your notebook. The collapsible headings nbextension is not supported in html yet. See the [discussion](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/847) on their repo.